# Styled Components Props React js

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I pass a property to my styled component. Basically I pass his height that starts with `400px`.

And when I click a button it will go to `30px`, but the way I did my `div` starts with `400px` and when I click the button it goes to `30px` and then doesn't expand the height size anymore:

```
export default function Menu() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true); // declare new state variable "open" with setter
    const handleClick = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setOpen(false);
    };
    return (
      <DivMenuButton height={open ? '400px' : '30px'}>
        <button
          style={{ margin:0, padding: 0, height: "30px", width: "100%", borderRadius:'0px' }}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Button
        </button>
      </DivMenuButton>  
    );
}
```

My styled component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const DivMenuButton = styled.div`
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #000; // was wrong syntax
    width: 200px;
    height: ${props => props.height}
`;
```

code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-nightingale-fsm58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually correct (almost).

The props and styled components parts are correct.

The thing you did wrong is that you always set open to false when clicking the button, instead of setting it to the opposite of what it was before.

So, instead of doing this:

```
const handleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setOpen(false);
};
```

you should do this:

```
const handleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setOpen(!open);
};
```

Comment: it worked but i got a little confused
I declared my state true
and when you click I set as false
is this incorrect?

Comment: @MykonSpt In reply to your first comment: Consider this: if you set the state to false every time you click it, it never becomes true again. You need to set it to the opposite of what it was before